# LeetCode #70 Climbing Stairs, How to speed up my solution?

Tags: javascript, recursion, optimization, dynamic-programming, trampolines

I have a solution to this problem on LeetCode #70 Climbing stairs, My solution is not passing, due to it being slow...

I have added a trampoline utilizing thunks and I've added Memoization, what else can I add to speed this up to actually pass the time requirement for this problem my code is below, and thanks in advance.

The description on LeetCode:

You are climbing a stair case. It takes n steps to reach to the top.

Each time you can either climb 1 or 2 steps. In how many distinct ways can you climb to the top?

Note: Given n will be a positive integer.

```
Example 1:

Input: 2
Output: 2
Explanation: There are two ways to climb to the top.
1. 1 step + 1 step
2. 2 steps


Example 2:

Input: 3
Output: 3
Explanation: There are three ways to climb to the top.
1. 1 step + 1 step + 1 step
2. 1 step + 2 steps
3. 2 steps + 1 step
```

Link to problem on LeetCode: https://leetcode.com/problems/climbing-stairs/

```
let cache = {};

const sumStairSteps = arr => arr.reduce((acc, cur) => acc + cur, 0);

const thunk = (fn, ...args) => {
    return () => fn(...args);
}

const climbStairsHelper2 = fn => {

    let thunk = fn();

    while (typeof thunk === "function") {
        thunk = thunk();
    }

    return thunk;
};

const climbStairs2 = (newStairSequence, ladderCount) => {
    const sum = sumStairSteps(newStairSequence);

    if (sum === ladderCount) {  cache[ladderCount] = cache[ladderCount] + 1; }


    if (1 + sum <= ladderCount) {
        climbStairsHelper2(thunk(climbStairs2, [ ...newStairSequence, 1 ], ladderCount));
    }

    if (2 + sum <= ladderCount) {
         climbStairsHelper2(thunk(climbStairs2, [ ...newStairSequence, 2 ], ladderCount));
    }
};

const climbStairs = n => {
        if (n in cache) return cache[n];
        cache[n] = 0;
        climbStairs2([], n);
        console.log(cache[n]);
        return cache[n];
};
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do here?

Comment: I'm trying to increase the speed of my solution.

Comment: No, I mean, can you explain what the code you posted is intended to do?

Comment: I'm using Memoization with Recursion, also I'm using a trampoline with thunks to avoid a stack overflow exception.

Comment: But what is the problem you're actually trying to solve?

Comment: I added a link with an a additional explanation, I apologize for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't quite follow the approach you're using here. The problem is actually pretty straightforward: code the naive recursive solution, then [memoize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) the results. That is, if you visit a stair in the cache, return it, otherwise compute it. Runtime is linear.

```js
const climbStairs = (goal, curr=0, memo={}) => {
  if (goal < curr) {
    return 0;
  }
  else if (goal === curr) {
    return 1;
  }
  else if (curr in memo) {
    return memo[curr];
  }
  
  return memo[curr] = climbStairs(goal, curr + 1, memo) +
                      climbStairs(goal, curr + 2, memo);
};

console.log(climbStairs(50));
```

Comment: Is There someway to get my solution to be more optimized?

Comment: Sure, you can drop thunks, spreading, summation, extra helpers and other unnecessary steps and slap on the memo as I show here but I'm not sure how instructive this is, and it seems to equate to a rewrite. I don't see a single obvious way to fix the code, in other words, but I also don't really understand the fundamental approach.

Comment: Yeah I basically had to throw it in the trash and redo it...

Comment: How would this be changed if it used tabulation?

Comment: @chocalaca That's a bit beyond the recursive question here, and the bottom-up solution is widely available on a quick search or in the solution thread on Leetcode. But basically create a 1d array, fill in the base cases, then loop forward and add up results from 1 and 2 steps back for each step. As [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74303824/6243352) suggests, it's the Fibonacci sequence, and you can replace the O(n) space array with plain variables that hold the last couple of values for O(1) memory.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so you want the solution to be more optimised.

**The solution which is currently being discussed by you has linear runtime i.e. O(N) and is accepted on LeetCode.**
For now let's not talk about the space complexity.

**This problem and a category of these problems can be solved by a method called Matrix Exponentiation which has logarithmic runtime i.e. O(Log N)**

Matrix Exponentiation is very well described at this link

https://discuss.codechef.com/t/building-up-the-recurrence-matrix-to-compute-recurrences-in-o-logn-time/570

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this problem by using ***Fibonnacci Series***

Here is my code that passed all test cases

```
    public int ClimbStairs(int n) 
    {
        
            //FIBONACCI SOLUTION

            // base cases
            if (n <= 0) return 0;
            if (n == 1) return 1;
            if (n == 2) return 2;

            int one = 2;
            int two = 1;
            int temp = 0;

            for (int i = 2; i < n; i++)
            {
                temp = one + two;
                two = one;
                one = temp;
            }
            return temp;
        
    }
```